# Vue datepicker render issue

Tags: vue.js, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Vue and Vue bootstrap via CDN and I am having issue with vue-bootstrap datepicker. For some reason there are two big blue boxes. Also the help-label is overflowing:
[image]

The date picker is registered in the bootstrap table:

```
<template #cell(date)="data">
    <b-form-datepicker size="sm" class="m-2" v-model="data.item.date" :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }"></b-form-datepicker>
</template>
```

Any idea what could be wrong? It is in large Flask project and for most frontend stylung it is using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Easiest way to figure out what the issue is, is inspecting the elements in your browser.
Should tell you which styles are being applied and from where.